# how does this "invisible code" work?

Tags: javascript

```
 []['map']['constructor']('console.log(1)')();
```

This line of code outputs '1' in my js file, by itself. According to Martin Kleppe, how this breaks down:

```
 []['map'] becomes function

 function['constructor'] becomes Function

 Function('console.log(1)')() becomes eval('console.log(1)')
```

Could there possibly be an **Explain Like I'm Five *Stacks Edition*** for this, in simpler Javascript logic? Because when **Martin** explained it, he had skipped many steps for a beginner like me :(

Source: https://youtu.be/T3xMyZH93i8?t=15m18s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[]['map']['constructor']('console.log(1)')();
```

Remember JavaScript supports square-bracket- and dot-syntax for interrogating objects.

So the first part is equivalent to

```
[].map.constructor
```

...where `[]` creates a new array. This array inherits (on its prototype) a `map()` method, which in turn inherits, on *its* prototype, a reference to the `Function` constructor (since `map()` is a function.)

So all of this was just a convoluted route to `Function()`. We could replace `map()` with any other array method e.g. `forEach` or `reduce`, or not use arrays at all, e.g.

```
document['querySelector']['constructor']
```

...since every method inherits from `Function()`.

Now, `Function()` allows you to create dynamic functions by passing the body of the function as a string to its first and only argument.So:

```
var myFunc = new Function('alert("hello from my func");');
```

This technique is almost never used and comes with the [same security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060696/security-considerations-using-new-function-during-rendertime-expression#answer-18062013) as `eval()`. There's rarely a good reason (or safe way) to evaluate string as code, in any language. (That said, it's worryingly common in frameworks as a means to allow JS-based instructions and syntax in DOM attributes, for example, e.g. Framework7).

In your example, the function being dynamically created is one which logs the integer 1 in the console.

Finally, the trailing `()` [immediately executes](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) our created function. It's not assigned to a variable; it's merely executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[]
```

Thats an *Array Literal*. It creates a new array.

```
['map']['constructor']
```

This is *bracket notation* for accessing an objects ( the arrays) property. Cause map is a *function*, its *constructor* is the global `Function` function.

```
('console.log(1)')
```

This calls the `Function` function with some code as the first argument. This returns a new function with the code we passed inside of it ( bad black magic ).

```
()
```

Now we call that function.

Answer (score 0):

`[]['map']['constructor']('console.log(1)')();`:

1. `[]`: is an array (instance of `Array`)
2. `['map']`: is bracket notation accessing the property `map` of the array from **1.**
3. `['constructor']`: accessing using the bracket notation the `constructor` property of the function `map` from **2.** which is `Function`
4. `('console.log(1)')`: Calling `Function` from **3.** with the string `"console.log(1)"` that will return a function whose definition is: `function() { console.log(1) }`.
5. `()`: calling the function returned from **4.** which will log `1` to the console.